# Automatic Google search

Tags: php, jquery, web, asp-classic, google-search-api

Is there some sort of web API that allows me to send a search query to google and get the number of search results?
I have been googling for something like this, and could not find anything.

Thank you,

Marina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well here is the Code with little description 
1. PHP curl enabled curl extension in php.ini
2. Google Ajax api

and i hope this code help you... i checked on localhost working fine for me .

```
<?php
echo Google_result('Hamza');

function Google_result($search){
$url="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=search:".$search."&filter=0";
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data=json_decode($json,true);
if($data['responseStatus']==200)
return $data['responseData']['cursor']['resultCount'];
else
return false;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes Google Ajax api will help you to do this

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=search:".$search."&filter=0
```

Comment: I can't use this API because I am not on Google's domain :(

Comment: dude i used on localhost and its working fine who said to you you must on host on Google domain etc